# Replace form elements with multiple custom images

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form of checkboxes which each need to be replaced with a different image. I've found a few plugins which can replace checkbox/radio fields with a custom image, however these plugins only work with a single image. (I can see that from a usability standpoint that in a traditional sense, you wouldn't want a bunch of different images for a radio/checkbox field).

To make things more complicated, in addition to replacing the checkbox with a custom image, I will also be overlaying another image on top of this!

Any suggestions on accomplishing this?

Thanks

EDIT: Both images should be visible, i.e., the custom checkbox image is largest, with the the additional overlay image being smaller.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is set the display of the checkbox to none.  Then add a `.mousedown()` event to the image that runs this code: `$('#checkbox_id').click()`. And thats how you set up a custom image for a checkbox.

If you have another image over-top of the checkbox image, whill you be able to see the checkbox image?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to see both images: both the custom checkbox image, and the additional overlay. The custom checkbox image will be largest.

Comment: @meta.matt Everything made sense until that last part.  What do you mean the checkbox image will be the largest?  As in the image will be larger than the overlay?

Comment: The custom checkbox image will be, let's say, 80px by 80px; the overlay image will be centered on the custom checkbox image, and be smaller, let's say, 20px by 20px. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @meta.matt ok, then try what I said, bind to only the larger image and absolutely position the smaller overlay.  Should work fine